# How to get notified (and able to cancel) when switching tabs

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

### background

I have a viewPager and a tabHost which are used to navigate between pages.

On some cases , the fragment within the viewPager would want to disallow navigating , and even show a dialog to ask the user to verify that the changes that were done in the fragment will be canceled .

If the user confirmed , I would allow navigating , and if not , I would disallow it.

### The problem

I need to get notified when the user attempts to navigate to another tab , and (under some conditions i've created) disallow/allow it .

### What I've tried

The only functionality i've found is how to disable the switching .

for viewPager , i use :

```
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
        return !mIsTabsSwitchingEnabled;
    }
});
```

and for the tabHost , i use:

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setEnabled(mIsTabsSwitchingEnabled);
```

However , what i need is quite different - i need to capture the event of starting to navigate , and be able to tell it if i allow it or not .

### The question

How should i solve this problem ?

How can i get notified when starting to navigate , and cancel it if needed ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Tab[TabHost.OnTabChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html)

Comment: Using TabHost.OnTabChangeListener is an incorrect solultion, since it is being called AFTER the tab was switched. I need to be informed BEFORE you try to switch to another tab , so that I could cancel it if needed.

Comment: @androiddeveloper This sounds like breaking the usual user-experience rules. I strongly suggest using a different method for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i agree , but this is something that was requested by my client , and i've told him that it's a weird behavior. However , the fragment contains some editing views which allow to save the info to the server , so we need to have something that should occur when you switch to other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

ok , i've solved it for now by using the next code , which i hope that it covers everything .

if anyone can think of another solution that might be better , please write it down .

```
final OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
        return isCurrentFragmentNeedTabSwitchingBlocking();
    }
};
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); ++i) 
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(tabOnTouchListener);
```